# Using a variable as folder name in a path php

Tags: php, image, variables, path, directory

I am trying to make this listing website in PHP, and I've come to the part with the images. Every item on the site has an unique ID, and the images are saved in a folder with that id as a name. I have trouble displaying the images in a loop using that ID variable as a folder name in the path. Any ideas?

```
$files = glob("images/$id/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo $num;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem, do you get any errors?

Comment: Nope, just an empty page. 
I think it has something to do with the way you express variables in the path field, maybe? 
Code works just fine with a path like $files = glob("images/*.*");

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($id);` ?

Comment: You should specifically point out the problem here, is it that because you are displaying text and not links to your image or do you want to display the image itself?

Comment: string(2) "53"  

53 is the id of the page

Comment: The full code has an image display. And it works, as long as $files = glob("images/$id/*.*"); does not contain a variable.

Comment: you are missing a closing brace for `for` loop, that's probably why you're seeing this white page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$files = glob("images/" . $id . "/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo $num;
```

Comment: I also had to change the $i to 0, but now it works! Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the solution? Why doesn't the OP's original code work? It seems to [output a valid path](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a79534449cfcefcb73584ac3a849a7654ab917e1).